# ORA-14102: only one LOGGING or NOLOGGING clause may be specified

Tags: oracle11g

While importing an oracle schema from  dump file, i am getting below error while creating tables.

`ORA-14102: only one LOGGING or NOLOGGING clause may be specified`.

I see the above error while creating tables from the dumpfile for several tables.

How to enable or disable LOGGING/NOLOGGING at schema level before i start import?

Answer (score 1):

When performing an Oracle database export with the expdp of Oracle 11gR2 (11.2.0.1) and then importing it into the database with impdp, the following error messages appear in the import log file:

> ORA-39083: Object type INDEX failed to create with error:
>
> ORA-14102: only one LOGGING or NOLOGGING clause may be specified

This is a known Oracle 11gR2 issue. The problem is that the DBMS_METADATA.GET_DDL returns invalid syntax for an index created. So, during the index creation, both the NOLOGGING and LOGGING keywords are visible in the DDL. Download and apply Patch 8795792 from Oracle to resolve this issue.